# Blender problem with lights not showing in Eevee, but working in Cycles

Tags: blender, lighting

I've been having some problems in blender with the lighting of my scene showing in Cycles,  but not in Eevee. I do have lights in the scene that have adequate brightness, and the only thing that isn't all dark (what it looks like in Eeevee) is the emission from the fire and the stars in the background.

I tried rendering in Cycles, and the lighting turned out just how I wanted, but not in Eevee. I'm using blender 3.5, and the strange thing is that the lighting showed up in all my projects before, but now, it isn't showing up in any of my previous projects where it has either. I've also downloaded 3.6, and the lighting worked in that until I put the character in the scene. However, something I noticed is that in Eevee, the lighting showed up eventually when I zoomed out really far away.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJqV3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDL0n.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a render in Blender 3.6.

The issue was that my model contained an object (a terrain envelope) with a 'big' solidify modifier of 136 meters. It was hidden in the viewport but I forgot to 'disable it in renders' (the camera icon in the outliner was 'on').

This 'envelope' acted like a huge container of my main items on the scene. So it seems that all my sun lights were unable to show up through it.
Like you, lighting showed up when I zoomed out.

So you could try to 'disable in renders' some of your items to check if one of them is 'obscuring' your lights.